# Customize component in Angular2/4 depending on where it is used

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following components in my application:

1. NavbarComponent
2. HomeComponent
3. ClassroomComponent

I use NavbarComponent in both HomeComponent and ClassroomComponent like this:

```
// home.component.html 

<app-navbar></app-navbar>
..something related to HomeComponent

// classroom.component.html

<app-navbar></app-navbar>
..something related to ClassroomComponent
```

I want to customize navbar depending on where it is used: for example, if it's used in HomeComponent, I want it to be red, and if otherwise, then set its color to green.
Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I think you'd need to use the router for that.

Comment: Yeah, not exactly what you want but maybe you can code something based on this: https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `:host-context` selector to define the component styles based on it's ancestor.

For your example it should be working like this:

```
// inside app-navbar css file
// where 'home-component' is the selector of your HomeComponent
:host-context(home-component) {
  background: red; // NavbarComponent is red when inside HomeComponent;
}

:host-context(classroom-component) {
  background: blue; // NavbarComponent is blue when inside ClassroomComponent;
}
```

More about special CSS selectors can be found [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors).

Comment: Thank you, it has helped! 
One more question. In my case, navbar has a complex structure with usage of different classes. Is there any way I can affect not only navbar itself, but also its child classes?
Something like this:
`:host-content(home-component) {
       background: red;
       
       .topnav a {
              text-align: center;
       }
`

Comment: You could just target children like: `:host-context(my-selector) .child-class { ... }`. If you want to target children inside child components you should look at the  `::ng-deep` selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your component in different ways

1. By using Provider(injection) to access global values
2. By using Event (publisher/subscriber methodology) procedure  http://learnangular2.com/events/
3. You can define a @Input decorator in the NavbarComponent https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5741 or http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-custom-event-binding-eventemitter-example